# Defining variable in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I define the variable `lists` as shown below and type `lists` in the console, I get the error `ReferenceError: lists is not defined`

```
var lists = new Meteor.Collection('Lists');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "my list.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

It works only if I declare `lists` as a global variable:

```
lists = new Meteor.Collection('Lists');
```

**Question:** Why must it be scoped global?

Comment: [A JavaScript Primer For Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/javascript-for-meteor/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access `lists` in the console you need to use a Global scope as the console is outside the scope of the file itself as the Console is considered its own file.

With `var` you can access `lists` anywhere in the file.

In essence each file is wrapped in a `function() {..}`. This is why each file's variables can't be accessed outside of them.

The reason that variable scoping exists is slightly more complicated, but more related to the third party packages/npm modules. Each package needs to have its own scope that wont have name collisions with stuff outside.

If you want to be able to use it more normally you could put it in the `/compatibility` folder too.